# How do I get a list of TFS Collections over REST?

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working with the REST API for Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online. I am looking for a rest call which will tell me what collections the user has access to.

I cannot find a REST call which will allow me to view this information. Is there a REST call that will let me view this information for an authenticated user?

Comment: Maybe [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/project-collections) can help.

Comment: I've taken a look at that, however, the call on that page to get all permissions requires elevated permissions (Edit instance-level information), just to view the permissions, which most users will not have. However I cannot find a call to do this, which is the issue I am having

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
[tfs url]/_api/_common/GetJumpList?showTeamsOnly=false&__v=5&navigationContextPackage={}&showStoppedCollections=false
```

You can capture the request by using developer tool: [Using Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The following works for Azure DevOps 2020:

```
[tfs url]/_apis/projectCollections?$top=1000
```

Comment: On 12/20/2021, this answer DID work on ADS 2020 and the accepted answer (from starian chen-MSFT) did NOT work on ADS 2020.